# Unable to Retrieve URL of Uploaded Image File in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My uploaded file (abc.png) is being saved in the folder:

`storage\app\public\uploaded_files\abc.png`

When I use `$url = Storage::disk('public')->url($business->logo);` it generates `http://127.0.0.1:8000//storage/abc.png` which rather opens a URL related to a route.

In **filesystem.php** I have the following entry.

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

**Route**

```
Route::get( '/{business_slug}/{item_name}-{encoded_id}', 
    'ItemController@single' )->name( 'single_item' );
```

What should I do to fix the image URL and make it available publicly?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? What is wrong with the given URL? How does that other route definition relate to a single asset?

Comment: Maybe an easy fix, did you [link the storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) folder with your public folder? It's posted as a comment, thanks @TimLewis

Comment: @NikolaGavric No problem! If that turns out to be the issue, you're more than welcome to restore your answer. Concern was that answers with a question in them tend to be flagged as "Not an answer", so better to clarify and convert if necessary.

Comment: I agree totally, assumptions are for comments until we have a clearer picture of the problem, you were totally right @TimLewis

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks, This helped. So on production I will have to run `php artisan storage:link` as well.

Comment: @Volatil3 Correct; `php artisan storage:link` generates a `symlink` between `storage/app` and `public`, so your images/files are in a secure location, but also available via a URL from something like `storage/image.png` (assuming `public` folder is mapped to `/`, which unless changed should be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

I see that your problem has been solved, but I'll leave another solution:

If you store your file in your public folder (or a subfolder in the public folder), you can easily access the file by using

```
{{ asset('images/' . $image) }}
```

The $image is just the filename, with it`s extension, and is being linked the to the subfolder 'images' in the public folder. This will work on any sub-page.